# Tizen tv app creation using pre-existing built vue app(dist)

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv-emulator

I built a vue(version 2) app that shows simple information from a db. Its nothing fancy and has user input all it does is shows data. It works on everything Ive tried and now I want to use a Tizen TV app to display it. Ive put all files from my `/dist` folder into the Tizen project and when I run it on an emulator I get a white screen. Ive checked the logs from the simulator but have no errors.
Is it possible to integrate my built app into the Tizen app or do I need to re-write my application?
My Tizen app structure looks like this after copying all the files from my `/dist` folder to the project:
MyProject
- static/
- config.xml
- iccn.png
- index.html
- service-worker.js

Comment: So, how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your app using Tizen Studio to see what's happening. Import the project into Tizen Studio and debug it. Please keep in mind that the simulator does not support the Samsung Tizen API's. You need to test/debug your app on the emulator.